# PHP & Json - Blank results returned with no errors

Tags: php, json

We had used this code in the past, I've put a non working example together the script will get some json data and present it through a wordpress template. Now it doesn't return data correctly or something is wrong with the feed here: http://www.testdomain.com/website

```
<?php
$url = "http://testdomain.com/website/";
$ch = curl_init($url);
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Contet-type: application/json'),
    );

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

$json = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($json);

?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($obj)`?

Comment: The problem ended up being a change in the content that was being curled. Thanks to @Michael for helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to add www to your url, then it's working again!

```
$url = "http://www.testdomain.com/website/";
```

Try it like this on a blank page:

```
$url = "http://www.testdomain.com/website/";

$ch = curl_init($url);
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Contet-type: application/json'),
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

$json = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($json);
var_dump($obj); //<<<< just to see the output
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer. This is just what I needed to know - perfect help really!

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I'll have a look on this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64879/discussion-between-joncav-and-michael).

Answer (score 1):

Json php functions does not trigger errors or warnings when somethign goes wrong.

Most of the times it's related to problems with encoding or parsing JSON on decode or encode

Use [json_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to check for errors.

Comment: Thanks for saying that, I'm not used to json and I was thinking that I was going crazy. This is a great help!

Answer (score 1):

please use 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

anyway, this seems to work

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$obj=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://example.com/website/"));
var_dump($obj);
```

(although, this approach has some up's and some down's, it won't work if allow_url_fopen is 0 , also it's probably slower than curl, as it doesn't give a shit about the content-length: header, it wait for the connection to close, i think.. on the plus side, it works even if php5-curl is not installed)

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @michael's answer, i got it.
seems http://testdomain.com/website/ is redirecting to http://www.testdomain.com/website/
, and by default, curl does not follow the redirects, add

```
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>true
```

like

```
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Contet-type: application/json'),
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>true
);
```

on a side note, seems Contet-type: application/json  header makes no difference..

Comment: Thank you for the extra side note - I will trim.